# Decide Table name dynamically in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi I have procedure which uses the table names based upon the year which I'm passing. How can I use it in sproc?

Ex: `tables_2000`,
`tables_2001`,...

Comment: What flavor of sql are you using?  Dynamic sql could prove to be an answer but it varies from sql provider. Also you should always tag that in your question.

Comment: That is a most unfortunate schema.  Presumably each table has identical structure?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @wallyk I agree but have seen worse.  Thought crossed my mind to create a view that would union all of them and have a year field so that could query based off of that.  Very inefficient but at least would resolve the bad schema design.

Comment: If you have control of the schema you can think about partitioning a single table by year.

Comment: Using SQL 2005. The tables are not limited and schema is same. And I need to create an alias for the tables in where condition

Answer (score 0):

Just going to throw this out there to help resolve the bad schema design.

create a view and then do a where clause on the view based on year

```
SELECT 2000 AS Year, *
FROM tables_2000
UNION
SELECT 2001 AS Year, *
FROM tables_2001
UNION
SELECT 2002 AS Year, *
FROM tables_2002
UNION
...etc
```

This assumes all tables_20XX have the same schema.

You could probably do this more efficiently using dynamic sql but you have not specified your sql vender in the tag or the question.

Comment: This schema was probably chosen to speed up things a little. Such a view would have an opposite effect. If possible, create just one table, or maybe a table for the current year and one for the whole history. The history table will be slower, but contains all data. The current year table is faster and can (probably) be used in most cases, if you need the history less often.

Comment: Still bad design in my opinion.  An index on year would almost completely resolve those issues.

Comment: Even a relationship table between year and historyId would be applicable.  Creation of multiple tables for each year is simply bad design.  Sometimes developers have to deal with that.  I know I work in a company where many of the initial databases were access designed by engineers with no knowledge of proper database design or programming.  Happens all the time and you just have to live with it and make work arounds of the initial design.

Comment: Or you can alter the design. But in some cases in index won't help. If the amount of data is simply too large.. But in general, yes, use one table and give it proper indexes.